# Set a width for a flexbox child but let it collapse?

Tags: css

I've set `flex: 1` for the right and left columns, this is to always make the middle column centralised even if the left and right columns are different widths.

But, how can I set a width for the middle column, and when the screen gets too narrow, the middle column gets smaller than it's set width?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

.middle {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    Left column
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    Middle column
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right column
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u3vy0fgs/5/

Comment: When I run your code snippet in JSFiddle, it appears to function as requested. Could you provide a more detailed explanation of what you're looking to do?

Comment: Left column and right column wrap, i dont want them to shrink this way.

Comment: They are wrapping to a new line? In the provided example that are shrinking before the middle column, but they don't seem to be wrapping for me.

Comment: "*i dont want them to shrink this way*": In what way do you want them to shrink?

Comment: I dont want the words to wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  min-width: fit-content;
  background: yellow;
}

.middle {
 background: blue;
 flex: 0 2 200px;
}

.right {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  min-width: fit-content;
  text-align: right;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
Left column
</div>
<div class="middle">
Middle column
</div>
<div class="right">
Right column
</div>
</div>
```

There are a couple changes you need to make to accomplish what you seek.

1. You are explicitly setting the width of `.middle`. You want to convert that to use `flex-basis`. That will allow FlexBox to handle the size.
2. You need to enable `flex-shrink` on the `.middle` element. This will allow FlexBox to take liberties regarding the shrinkage of the element compared to other elements.
3. You need to disable `flex-shrink` on the `.left` and `.right` elements. This  will prevent them from shrinking below their content width. This combined with #2 will make FlexBox prefer shrinking the element with the higher `flex-shrink` value.
4. In order for the middle element to be truly centered, you need to make sure the `flex-basis` of `.left` and `.right` are equal. In my example, I set them both to zero. To prevent the text from wrapping in those elements, make sure to add [`min-width: fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content) to both `.left` and `.right`.

*Note: In my code snippet, I'm using the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) shorthand property*

Comment: This doesn't work, the middle column is no longer centralised.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I just doublechecked and it is in the middle of the screen until the container is too small to contain the content of `.left` and `.right`

Comment: Your left column is 201px wide, your right column is 210px wide, therefore the middle column is not central.

Comment: I see the issue now. I've updated my answer to account for this.

Comment: This is good, but not quite there. On smaller screen sizes, the left column does not maintain the same width as the right column, see: https://jsfiddle.net/o5Ldta8w/ I have made the left column contents just to be an "L" to better show the effect. I suspect a way around this would be to manually set the flex basis on the L and R columns to the max size of the largest column for example: flex: 1 0 250px;

Comment: I think in order to solve that problem and maintain it's ability to be dynamic, JavaScript will be needed. If you know what the content of the largest element will be, you can forgo the `min-width` and just set the the `flex-basis` to that from the jump

Comment: My pleasure! Glad I was able to offer some assistance.